# UITableView is not showing data, used as iCarousel View

Tags: ios, uitableview, icarousel

(Making an iPad app)In my `iCarousel` there are two `UITableViews` when i swipe to next `iCarousel` view then i am getting nothing in `UITableView`. When i keep the `numberOfRowsInsection` as constant then there is no problem. But when i try to change the `datasource` of `UITableView` either i am getting `NSRangeException` or nothing in `UTableView`.Here is the code what i done.
 Please help. I am stuck here.

```
#pragma mark-Table View Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 5;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSInteger carouselIndex = [self.carousel indexOfItemViewOrSubview:tableView];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    NSArray *array= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"toursViewTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

    toursViewTableCell *cell = (toursViewTableCell*) [array objectAtIndex:0];

    switch (carouselIndex) {
        case 0:
            if (tableView.tag==111) {
                if (cell==nil) {
                    cell= [[toursViewTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];     
                }

                //setting dataSource
                dateArrayInTableCellOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2014-05-08",@"2014-05-09",@"2014-05-11",@"2014-05-13",@"2014-05-14", nil];
                cityArrayInTableCellOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Santa Cruz",@"Redding",@"Portland",@"Boise",@"Salt Lake City", nil];
                stateArrayInTableCellOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"CA",@"CA",@"OR",@"ID",@"UT" ,nil];
                venueArrayInTableCellOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Catalyst Club",@"Cascade Theater",@"Alladin Thearter",@"Knitting Factory",@"The Depot", nil];

                //setting Cell

            }else if (tableView.tag==222){

                //setting dataSource for second tableView
                dateArrayInTableCellTwo=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2014-03-04",@"2014-03-05",@"2014-03-07",@"2014-03-08",@"2014-03-11", nil];
                cityArrayInTableCellTwo=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Richmond",@"Newport News",@"Charleston",@"Louisville",@"Des Moines", nil];
                stateArrayInTableCellTwo=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"VA",@"VA",@"WV",@"KY",@"IA",nil];
                venueArrayInTableCellTwo=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Carpenter Center",@"Christopher Newport Univ.",@"Clay Center for the Arts & Sciences",@"Palace Theatre",@"Civic Center of Greater Des Moines", nil];

                //Setting Cell
            }

        break;

        //Carousel Index Changed
        case 1:
            if (tableView.tag==111) {

                //I am not getting anything here,If i reload tableView . If i dont reload tableView I am getting NSRangeException.

                //Changing dataSource
                newDateArrayInTableCellOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2014-01-16",@"2014-01-28",@"2014-01-29", nil];

                newCityArrayInTableCellOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Santa Barbara",@"New York City", nil];
                newStateArrayInTableCellOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"CA",@"NY",@"NY", nil];

                newVenueArrayInYableCellOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"The Lobero Theatre",@"City Winery",@"City Winery", nil];

                //setting Cell For Carousel Index One
            }else if (tableView.tag==222){
               //Setting TabeViewCell For Carousel Index One
            }
        break;
```

Here is the screenShot What I am trying to do.[image]

Comment: Your code is a bit messy, at which line there is a NSRangeException ?  Why do you call `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:newDateArrayInTableCellOne.count];` without getting the result ?

Comment: @Justafinger I edited and removed the messy stuff..Please have a look

Comment: I'm sorry but i believe we're missing some stuff. Nothing in what you show can cause an NSRangeException. When you say you keep `numberOfRowsInsection` as a constant it works, are you refering to the `return 5`. Do you always have 5 rows in each section ? Your picture shows 4. A lot of stuff don't really make sense.

Comment: @Justafinger where i should call `[TableView reloadData]` after changing datasource

Comment: Wherever you want but not in the tableview datasource methods.